# How to change timer

Tags: java, swing, timer

I'm not sure how to change the timer in my program.

I want to control the timer as the program runs.

This is my code:

```
Timer timer = new Timer(Difficulty, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                if(p.GameOver==0)
                {
                    if(p.s==1)
                    {
                        System.out.println("S");
                        p.moveSquare(p.SnakeHeadX,p.SnakeHeadY+p.SnakeHeadH);
                        p.eatBlueSquare(p.SnakeHeadX,p.SnakeHeadY);
                        p.Border(p.SnakeHeadX,p.SnakeHeadY);
                        p.Colision(p.SnakeHeadX,p.SnakeHeadY);
                    }
                    if(p.d==1)
                    {
                        System.out.println("D");
                        p.moveSquare(p.SnakeHeadX+p.SnakeHeadW,p.SnakeHeadY);
                        p.eatBlueSquare(p.SnakeHeadX,p.SnakeHeadY);
                        p.Border(p.SnakeHeadX,p.SnakeHeadY);
                        p.Colision(p.SnakeHeadX,p.SnakeHeadY);
                    }
                    if(p.a==1)
                    {
                        System.out.println("A");
                        p.moveSquare(p.SnakeHeadX - p.SnakeHeadW,p.SnakeHeadY);
                        p.eatBlueSquare(p.SnakeHeadX,p.SnakeHeadY);
                        p.Border(p.SnakeHeadX,p.SnakeHeadY);
                        p.Colision(p.SnakeHeadX,p.SnakeHeadY);
                    }
                    if(p.w==1)
                    {
                        System.out.println("W");
                        p.moveSquare(p.SnakeHeadX,p.SnakeHeadY-p.SnakeHeadH);
                        p.eatBlueSquare(p.SnakeHeadX,p.SnakeHeadY);
                        p.Border(p.SnakeHeadX,p.SnakeHeadY);
                        p.Colision(p.SnakeHeadX,p.SnakeHeadY);
                    }

                }

            }
        });
timer.start();
```

If I change difficulty as the program runs there is no effect.

Comment: `If I change difficulty as the program runs there is no effect.` - did you just change the difficulty variable, or did you actually invoke a method on the Timer to change the delay?

Answer (score 3):

Just use timer.setDelay(Difficulty) every time you update the difficulty.
For more info about timer see this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html

Answer (score 0):

you would have to cancel the current timer and then reinstantiate the timer with the correct value (where you would change the difficulty)

Comment: how do i cancel the timer?

Comment: @user3212504, `how do i cancel the timer?` did you read the Timer API?